# Wordpress 3.6 Video shortcodes in template

Tags: videos

I understand the video shortcodes work fine when inserted into a post. Easy.

What about when you want to have more control about where the video should be displayed.
I would like to use something like:

```
do_shortcode('[video webm="http://mb2013.mercerbell.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/sample_mpeg4.webmhd.webm" width="640" height="360" autoplay="true" loop="true"]')
```

or using the prebuilt WP function:

```
wp_video_shortcode( array('webm'=>'http://mb2013.mercerbell.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/sample_mpeg4.webmhd.webm") )
```

Neither of these solutions seem to work.

As anyone else managed to get this to work? Outside of the embedding it in a post scenario?

Much Appreciated.

Comment: There's a [Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode#Examples) for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the looks of it, you aren't `echo`-ing the [`do_shortcode` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode), which you should.

Try this:

```
<?php

    echo do_shortcode('[video webm="http://mb2013.mercerbell.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/sample_mpeg4.webmhd.webm" width="640" height="360" autoplay="true" loop="true"]');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks Just having a dig into the wordpress code, this seems to work.

    <?php echo wp_video_shortcode(array('src'=>'http://mb2013.mercerbell.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/sample_mpeg4.webmhd.webm') ); ?>

I would like to be able to add in multiple video files, flash backup support and responsiveness. I'll update when I figure it out. :)

Comment: You shouldn't use do_shortcode if you don't need to because it's a very resource intensive function. It would be best to use the actual shortcode function which is wp_video_shortcode as Michael mentioned above.